# Etiquette for publicizing postdoc position

Tags: application, postdocs

What is the etiquette for publicizing your postdoc decision on your professional website once you've accepted a position?

I've seen people write something like "Starting in Fall 2020, I will be an X Instructor/Fellow/Researcher at Y University" on their website but I don't know when these kinds of public statements typically go up. Are you supposed to wait until late in the process when most people know where they'll end up? Or if you're lucky enough to get a position early, is it ok to post then?

I'm specifically interested in comments relevant to math positions, but I'm assuming the etiquette is similar throughout STEM.

Answer (score 2):

You are unlikely to offend a reasonable person by revealing you got a job.  So I would say there is not an etiquette beyond avoiding excessive boasting.  Don't talk about how you are better than the people who did not get the job.  Don't talk about how your job is better than other people's jobs.  You probably knew that.

This is not etiquette, but:  If you get a job "early" it is in your interest to keep it secret for a while.  A lot of people think that "I have a new job starting in September" is the same as "I am leaving tomorrow."  They will quit contacting you and quit collaborating with you because they are confused.  You will constantly have to answer questions about why you are still around.

Comment: I doubt that the last paragraph applies to a student taking their first post-doc position.

Comment: No, students need collaborators and they sometimes get jobs that do not start for many months.

Comment: Thanks! I was really asking about posting to a professional website specifically. I definitely wouldn't go around boasting out loud or telling people that I'm better than them, that would be pretty bad.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: In math in academia in the US, up to a first and second approximation, all jobs start in August.  If you tell someone now (or told someone two months ago when the first offers came out) that you got a new job, the assumption will be that it starts in August.  If anything, we are getting close to the time of the year when I would be reluctant to start a collaboration with a student or a postdoc who did not have a job offer, because they might end up forced to take a job that does not leave them time for research to continue and finish whatever we are working on.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I knew that; the point I was making is that many people who are inexperienced or not academics do not know that, and you should be careful with how you communicate with them so they do not think you already left.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: Note that not everyone knows about US math start conventions.